# Empty lines in QStandardItemModel with custom data

Tags: c++, qt

The header is ok, but I only have three empty lines.

The method FileConfig::data is never called!
Have you any idea why?

```
model= new MyModel;

model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Title"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Direcory"));
model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Date"));

model->invisibleRootItem()->setChild(0, new FileConfig("/home/user/dir/riri.conf"));
model->invisibleRootItem()->setChild(1, new FileConfig("/home/user/dir/fifi.conf"));
model->invisibleRootItem()->setChild(2, new FileConfig("/home/user/dir/loulou.conf"));

proxy= new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxy->setSourceModel(model);

view= new QTreeView;
view->setModel(proxy);
```

MyModel inherite from QStandardItemModel, empty for the moment.
My custom class:

```
class FileConfig : public QStandardItem {
    public:
        std::string getFileName() const;
        std::string getFileDirectory() const;
        std::string getDate() const;

        FileConfig(const char *fileconfig);

        virtual QStandardItem *clone() const;
        virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role= Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    private:
        boost::filesystem::path file;
};

FileConfig::FileConfig(const char *fileconfig) : QStandardItem() {
    file= boost::filesystem::path(fileconfig);
}

QVariant FileConfig::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        switch(index.column()) {
            case 0: return getFileName().c_str();
            case 1: return getFileDirectory().c_str();
            case 2: return getDate().c_str(); }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `appendRow` instead of `setChild` when you add new items to the model.  For example:

```
model->invisibleRootItem()->appendRow(new FileConfig(/*path*/));
```

Edit: you also need the Q_OBJECT macro in your class definition of `FileConfig`, otherwise signals and slots will not work.  Remember to re-run QMake after you add the macro.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I did what you suggested but I get exactly the same result.
qDebug () in FileConfig is not running!

Comment: You definitely re-ran QMake after adding the macro, right?  Try doing a rebuild or clean/build too.

Comment: Yes, I even completely delete the build directory.

Comment: And you put a breakpoint on the first line of `FileConfig::data()`, but the debugger never stopped?

Comment: At no time FileConfig::data is run. I do not use debugger, only qDebug() << "I passed here";